Правильно ли проставлена запятая?
Правильно ли стоит запятая после "модифицированном варианте"?

Как в стандартном, так и в модифицированном варианте(,) этот велосипед выпускался десятками производителей.


Запятая ставится при наличии обобщения: В ОБОИХ вариантах, как в стандартном, так и в модифицированном,  этот велосипед выпускался десятками производителей.

Или такая актуализация оборота (присоед. значение): Этот велосипед выпускался десятками производителей – как в стандартном, так и в модифицированном варианте.  А в начале предложения какая-либо актуализация невозможна.

@Sharon почему в начале не может быть актуализации оборота?

@Буратино Это просто обстоятельство, выраженное однородными членами.  Сравнить: В таких вариантах / этот велосипед выпускался десятками производителей.  Здесь ведь нет подчеркивания. Надо хотя бы так: Разработанный как в стандартном, так и в модифицированном вариантах, этот велосипед выпускался десятками производителей.  Здесь можно подчеркнуть значение "будучи разработанным".

А у Розенталя бывает вот так: п. 20. 1. Для смыслового выделения или для пояснения могут обособляться (выделяться запятыми) обстоятельства, выраженные существительными в формах косвенных падежей (обычно с предлогами), особенно если при этих существительных имеются пояснительные слова.

@Буратино  А это обстоятельство, вы уверены?

@Sharon Не особо уверен)

@Буратино  А какой тогда?  Можно сказать: велосипед какой? в каком варианте/вариантах? Тогда определение. Хотите поставить запятую?

@Sharon если честно, да, до сих пор хочу поставить, но понимаю, что не надо бы) Я бы запятые лепил где надо и где не надо.)

Отвечаете уклончиво, ага?  Почему же не надо? Грамматику не называете. Вообще-то актуализацию по контексту надо смотреть. А у нас в ответе:  не нужна здесь запятая. Вот и все объяснение. А союз "как...так и" там  вообще ни причем.

В этом предложении союз как... так и соединяет однородные определения.
Не нужна здесь вторая запятая.
Примеры
Как в простом, так и в сложном предложении основным грамматическим средством выражения сочинительных отношений является сочинительная связь (Е. А. Яковлева. К вопросу об определении грамматической однородности конструкций с союзом «и»
и их нормативном оформлении в письменной коммуникации).
Ведь мы сказали, что как внутри, так и снаружи Николая Ивановича ничего не существует (Д. И. Хармс. «Вот бутылка с водкой…»).
Как белые, так и красные судорожно цеплялись за железные дороги, узловые станции, защищались с особым упорством... (Борис Васильев. Дом, который построил Дед).
Как вчера, так и сегодня я последую за твоим рассуждением, куда бы оно ни повело (М. Т. Цицерон).

Возможна ли актуализация оборота?
Как в стандартном, так и в модифицированном варианте, ЭТОТ велосипед выпускался десятками производителей.

Кстати, какой это оборот: велосипед выпускался каким? Вряд ли можно сказать: выпускался в чем или где? Выпускался как? Тоже вряд ли. Тогда это не обстоятельственный оборот. (А вот примеры из ответа в основном обстоятельства.)

Тогда можно считать, что это  распространенное несогласованное определение, то есть вчера при обсуждении грамматика называлась неверно.

И что тут тогда интересного? А интересно то, что для распространенного определительного оборота актуализация возможна. В конечном итоге это определяется по контексту.


Сравнить: В течение многих лет этот велосипед выпускался  как в стандартном, так и в модифицированном варианте. // Как в стандартном, так и в модифицированном варианте, ЭТОТ велосипед выпускался в течение многих лет.
И возникает вопрос: зачем автор помещает оборот в начало предложения, для чего нужна эта инверсия оборота?
Мой вывод: Грамматика не названа, причина для отсутствия запятой не указана. Что касается союза КАК...ТАК И, то он связывает однородные определения в составе оборота и к обособлению оборота отношения не имеет. Вопросу уделили недостаточно внимания.
